# Create and populate landing pages dynamically using feed

Tags: php, xml, dynamic, rss, feed

I am trying to create multiple landing pages populated dynamically with data from a feed.

My initial thought was to create a generic php page as a template that can be used to create other pages dynamically and populate them with data from a feed. For instance, the generic page could be called landing.php; then populate that page and other pages created on the go with data from a feed depending on an id, keyword or certain string in the url. e.g http://www.example.com/landing.php?page=cars or http://www.example.com/landing.php?page=bikes will show contents that are either only about cars or bikes as the case may be.

My question is how feasible is this approach and is there a better way to create multiple dynamic pages populated with data from a feed depending on the url query string or some sort of id.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this quite extensively. For example, where I work, we often have education oriented landing pages, but target each landing page to different types of visitors. A good example may be arts oriented schools looking for a diverse array of potential students who may be interested in a variety of programs for any number of reasons.

Well, who likes 3d Modelling? Creative types (Generic lander => ?type=generic) from all sorts of social circles. Also, probably gamers (Gamer centric lander => ?type=gamer). So on.

I apply that variable to the body's class, which can be used to completely reorganize the layout. Then, I select different images for key parts of the layout based on that variable as well. The entire site changes. Different fonts can be loaded, different layout, different content.

I keep this organized via extensive includes. This sounds ugly, but it's not if you stick to a convention. You have to know the limitations of your foundation html, and you can't make too many exceptions. Sure, you could output extra crap based on if the type was gamer or generic, but you're going down the road to a product that should probably be contained in its own landing page if it *needs* to be that different.

I have a few landing pages which can be switched between several contents and styles (5 or 6 'themes'), but the primary purpose of keeping them grouped within the same url is only to maintain focus on the fact that *that's* where a certain type of traffic goes to in order to convert for *this* specific thing. Overlapping the purpose of these landing pages is a terrible idea.

Anyway, dream up a great template, outline a rigid convention for development, keep each theme *very* separate, and go to town on it. I find doing it right saves a load of time, but be careful - Doing it wrong can cost a lot of time too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  htaccess URL Rewrite. Then your user (and google) can use a url like domanin.com/landing/cars but on your server the script will be executed as if someone entered domain.com/landing.php?page=cars;

If you use feed content to populate the pages you should use some kind of caching to ensure that you do NOT reload all feed on every requests/reloads the page.

Checking the feeds every 1 to 5 minutes should be enough and the very structure of feeds allows you to identify new items easily.

About URL rewrite: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

A nice template engine for generating pages from feets is phptal (http://phptal.org)

You can load the feet as xml and directly use it in your template.

test.xml:

```
<foo><bar>baz!!!</bar></foo>
```

template.html:

```
<html><head /><body> ${xml/foo/bar}</body></html>
```

sample.php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$tal = new PHPTAL('template.html');
$tal->xml = $xml;
echo $tal->execute();
```

And it does support loops and conditional elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not needing real time data then you can do this in a few parts

A script which pulls data from your rss feeds and stores the data somewhere (sql db?), timed by something like cron. It could also tag the entries into categories.

A template in php taking the url arguments and then adding the requested data and displaying it for the user. Really quite easy to do with php, probably a good project to use to learn as well if you are that way inclined

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. All great ideas. I will try some of these approaches. For some reason my response was deleted. All the same well appreciated guys!